# How to create a dynamic number of datasets based on DB values

Tags: javascript, php, canvasjs

My goal is to render a graph in PHP using CanvasJS but with multiple datasets dynamically generated based on the values in a DB. Generating this graph with only 1 dataset was working just fine, making it "dynamic" seems to be a challenge.

For 1 dataset I used the code below:

```
        while ($row = $stm->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {   
            $score = calculateScore($row['difficulty'],$row['length']);
             array_push($dataPoint, array("x"=> $i , "y"=> $score)); 
            $i++;
        }
```

Where $dataPoint is send to the JS code

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(function () {
        var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer", {
            data: [
            {
                type: "line",

                dataPoints: <?php echo json_encode($dataPoint, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK); ?>
            }
            ]
        });
        chart.render();
    });
</script>
```

So far, so good, so, next step is to extend this to multiple datasets. In this case, for each user in the view "completedgames" we will create a new dataset $datapoint and each $datapoint will be added to the overal dataset $datapoints as shown below:

```
    while($rowUsers = $stmUsers->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
        
        $name = $rowUsers['username'];           

        $stm = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM public."completedgames" WHERE username = :username');
        $stm->bindParam(":username", $name, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stm->execute();   
        
        while ($row = $stm->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {   
            $score = calculateScore($row['difficulty'],$row['length']);
             array_push($dataPoint, array("x"=> $i , "y"=> $score)); 
            $i++;
        }
        array_push($dataPoints, $dataPoint);  
        $dataPoint = array();
    }
```

Where $dataPoints is the value now send to the same JS code as shown in above. Unfortunately this is where it goes wrong. data array_push() function doesn't feel right but I have no idea what the alternative is.

So, I hope this is sufficient information, all information is welcome and thanks in advance!

Comment: I would try the approach shown [here](https://canvasjs.com/docs/charts/basics-of-creating-html5-chart/multi-series-charts/) where have more than one element in the canvasjs `data` array

Comment: What's wrong with the current code? Does it create the dataset you need? You can use `$dataPoint[] = ["x"=>$i, "y"=>$score]` but end result should be the same.

Comment: Well, @James, that is where I started from, however, that is a fixed list, there is no example containing a dynamic dataset. 

And the current code does not generated the graph anymore. $dataPoint is fine, it's multiple $dataPoint adding in one big array that does not work.

Comment: You could create that whole `data` structure in php instead of just the dataPoint array.  Then you could add as many additional graphs to the chart as you want.

Comment: @James, thats the point, it's only 1 graph just multiple lines in that one graph. The amount of lines is based on the DB content

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using James' input I was able to make my Graph with multiple lines. Just needed to reset the counter and $dataPoint array: here is the working code:

```
    while($rowUsers = $stmUsers->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
        
        $name = $rowUsers['username'];           

        $stm = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM public."completedgames" WHERE username = :username');
        $stm->bindParam(":username", $name, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stm->execute();   
        
        while ($row = $stm->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {   
            $score = calculateScore($row['difficulty'],$row['length']);
             array_push($dataPoint, array("x"=> $i , "y"=> $score)); 
             json_encode($dataPoint, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
            $i++;
        }
        //array_push($dataPoints, $dataPoint);  
       // $dataPoint = array();
        
        array_push($charts, array("type" => "line", "dataPoints" => $dataPoint));
        $dataPoint = array();
        $i = 0;
    }
```

Thanks for all your inputs!

Answer (score 0):

You have a few different problems, first when appending the data I would do this:

```
$dataPoint[] = array("x"=> $i , "y"=> $score);
```

Also I would get rid of this as it seems to be clearing out `$dataPoint` and might actually be creating additional levels in the array.

```
array_push($dataPoints, $dataPoint);  
$dataPoint = array();
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I modified my code as per your suggestion but the result is the same. (modified the $dataPoint and removed the clear) The array_push($dataPoints, $dataPoint is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This code creates a `$charts` variable which looks like the `data` array in your javascript chart definition, rather than making a representation of just the `dataPoints` array.  That should allow you to have as many data sets as you want.

```
$charts = [];    

while($rowUsers = $stmUsers->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    
    $dataPoint = [];

    $name = $rowUsers['username'];           

    $stm = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM public."completedgames" WHERE username = :username');
    $stm->bindParam(":username", $name, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stm->execute();   
    
    while ($row = $stm->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {   
        $score = calculateScore($row['difficulty'],$row['length']);
         array_push($dataPoint, array("x"=> $i , "y"=> $score)); 
        $i++;
    }

    array_push($charts, array(
      "type" => "line",
      "dataPoints" => $dataPoint
    ));

}





<script type="text/javascript">

    $(function () {
        var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer", {
            data: <?php echo json_encode($charts, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK); ?>
        });
        chart.render();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the suggestion, there is improvement, all the data is now visible but in stead of having multiple lines, all values are now appended to the $charts dataset.

Comment: My thought was to have multiple lines on one chart, the same way as the Multi Series Line Chart on https://canvasjs.com/docs/charts/basics-of-creating-html5-chart/multi-series-charts/.  Is that not what you wanted?

Comment: That's exactly what it should be, however, there is now just 1 line but containing all values.

Comment: Check the rendered javascript "data" structure that gets fed into CanvasJS.Chart, I'd expect one element in the array per "user" in your stmUsers query, each element being an object with type and dataPoints properties.